# How to check whether a string contains any of a list of characters?

Tags: python, list

Even a word that contains a vowel when entered outputs "NO VOWELS HERE!". Why? Please assist.

```py
vowels = 'a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U'
I = input("enter your name")
L = list(I)
print(L)
if vowels in L:
    print("your name contains a vowel")
else:
    print("NO VOWELS HERE!")
```

Comment: Because the whole tuple `vowels` is not an element of `L`.

Comment: For everything else, you could do without duplicating sounds in a large register:
`vowels = "aeiou"
I = input ().lower ()`

Answer (score 4):

You have to compare each individual vowel.

```
vowels = 'a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U'
name = input("enter your name")
if any(vowel in name for vowel in vowels):
    print("your name contains a vowel")
else:
    print("NO VOWELS HERE!")
```

As you can see in this code `name` is not transferred to a list. You don't need that because a string is iterable. This means that you could do another change:

```
vowels = 'aAeEiIoOuU'
name = input("enter your name")
if any(vowel in name for vowel in vowels):
    print("your name contains a vowel")
else:
    print("NO VOWELS HERE!")
```

---

An example what happened in your original code:

```
>>> needle = 'a', 'b'
>>> needle in list('ab')
False
```

Let's check the values:

```
>>> needle
('a', 'b')
>>> list('ab')
['a', 'b']
```

You test if the tuple `('a', 'b')` is an element of `['a', 'b']`. As you can see it is not. The elements of the list are `'a'` and `'b'`. To be `True` the comparison would have to look like this.

```
>>> needle in [('a', 'b')]
True
```

You have to understand that you're comparing the exact tuple, not parts of it.

```
>>> needle in [('a', 'b', 'c')]
False
```

Comment: that worked, it did, but I am clueless what actually has happened. @Matthias, please elucidate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the intersection property of `set` for this:

```
vowels = set('aeiouAEIOU')
I = set(input("enter your name"))

if len(I & vowels)>0:
    print("your name contains a vowel")
else:
    print("NO VOWELS HERE!")
```

Explanation:

```
>>> vowels = set('aeiouAEIOU')
>>> vowels
{'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}
>>> I = set('John Doe')
>>> I
{' ', 'D', 'J', 'e', 'h', 'n', 'o'}
>>> (vowels & I)
{'e', 'o'}
```

`{'e','o'}` present in both strings.